# Galería de Google Web Designer

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo un anuncio con una swipe gallery. Tengo que deshabilitarle las flechas para correr hacia los costados cuando se está al principio o al final de la galería (ejemplo: que al llegar a la última imagen de la galería, la flecha que apunta hacia la derecha desaparezca o cambie de opacidad).

Debo aclarar que tengo que hacerlo desde el HTML5, ya que no cuento con el archivo del proyecto hecho en el programa. No sé si debo agregar alguna variable ni cómo hacerla.

El creativo es el siguiente: http://kickads.mobi/test/movistar/galeria/

El ID de las flechas son `gwd-image_6`y `gwd-image_5`

Comment: Para poder ayudarte en tu problema se necesita que envies el codigo fuente del carrusel con la librerias correspondientes que esta usando.